# Why constraint does not work programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, constraints

I want to change heightConstraint of my imageView when phone rotate ,i used below code:

```
var newPageView = UIImageView(image: nil)

override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newPageView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: newPageView.superview, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 600)
    newPageView.superview!.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
}
```

but it does not work. What is the mistake on my snippet?

Comment: Have you checked this link - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html

Comment: @Rajatp I want it in Swift, not in ObjC

Comment: What do you mean it does not work; does the image change size to something other than what you want or does it not change size at all?

Comment: You only need to set up your height constraint once on viewDidLoad or similar. The height will automatically resize based on your constraint when de device rotates. In your example you are adding the constraint over and over again each time the device rotates which may result in unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

1. For change height of `imageView` you need add constraint to `imageView`, not to the `superview`.
2. Before adding new height constraint you must remove previous height constraint.

I think it would be better to keep reference to constraint and change it when you need, than remove it and add. For example:

```
var imageView = UIImageView(image: nil)
var heightConstant : NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    heightConstant = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 800)
    imageView.addConstraint(heightConstant)
}

override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{
    heightConstant.constant = 600
}
```